# Default USB MTP for Android 6.0

Tags: usb-connection-mode, 6.0-marshmallow, mtp

I would like to have MTP selected by default (instead of charging) when I plug an Android 6.0.x device to a PC through a USB cable. What should I add or modify in the build.prop file of my rooted device to make this happen? I know that it's not possible to do that without root access but the device is rooted.

Comment: It doesn't work. The persist.sys.usb.config is already mtp,adb when plugging a USB cable and the "Charging" option is selected by default.

Comment: Do you have [Xposed Framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) installed? If yes, then [this module](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-usb-marshmallow-1-0-t3272072) may work for you. ([Source](http://nexus6-xda.blogspot.in/2015/12/xposed-set-mtp-or-ptp-as-default-usb.html)). Alternatively, see if this works: [How do we toggle on MTP more easily on a Debug-Enabled Android 6.0 device?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33549060)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I found so far is an application named MTPEnabler: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-mtp-enbaler-t3263467

Answer (score 5):

Google changed the USB protocol for Marshmallow to always default to charge.

The reason for this change because they brought back the ability to make external storage (SD card) become internal storage. Creating a new storage type called "Adoptable Storage".

Originally google removed the ability to swap storages because they viewed it as a huge security vulnerability.

[Adoptable storage](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable.html)

In order to achieve your end goal it looks like you might have to compile marshmallow from source. Find the `MtpService.java` and then with `updateDisabledStateLocked()` change `mMtpDisabled` to `false`.

[MtpService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/4599003425f9b83319805a3522aeb31bfd2f1d30/src/com/android/providers/media/MtpService.java)

Comment: Though your answer clearly answers the question (that requested functionality is not possible to achieve) I still don't understand what is the relation between using external storage as internal storage and default mode for USB connection. What SD card has to do with USB port?

Answer (score -1):

Through Developers Options it was possible in my phone.
Just goto

```
 Developer option > USB configuration
```

By default its set to `Charging`.
Change it to `MTP`. Try connecting USB, this should work.

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't work, we only wish it was that simple...

Comment: This works exactly one time. As soon as you disconnect, it reverts back. Note OP didn't want to know how to connect via MTP – but how to make that the default whenever the USB cable is connected. Your suggested approach works until Android 5 (Lollipop), but no longer with Marshmallow (Android 6) which OP explicitly asked for.

Comment: Yaa. It does reset back.