# USB configuration within Developer Options doesn't save

Tags: usb, 6.0-marshmallow

Just bought a Samsung Galaxy s7 Edge with Marshmallow pre-installed.
I'm trying to get my phone to work with Android Auto.

The only way I could make my phone connect to my car is to enable Developer Options in the settings menu and change the USB configuration to "MTP Media Transfer Protocol".

My problem is that whenever I disconnect my phone, the change I made goes away and reverts back to "charging".
So, now, every time I want to connect my phone to use Android Auto, I need to enter the settings and change the USB configuration back to MTP for it to work... really a pain in the butt.

Does anyone know if this is an Android issue or a Samsung issue? Also, is there a way to correct this?

Comment: It is [status-by-design](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-usb). Might help out: [Default USB MTP for Android 6.0](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/131931)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this issue is not limited to you. This is the same on my Nexuses (running Marshmallow) and it's a pain.