# Windows 10 won't recognize my Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: windows, samsung-galaxy-s-6

After an update to Win10, my phone will only charge.  I downloaded Samsung's USB drivers, installed Smart-Switch, checked my Device Manager...  Nothing.  The cable I'm using is definitely a data transfer cable.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the Android version? What does the notification say when you connect to laptop?

Comment: No notification at all.  It's like it's not even there.  I'm using 6.0.1.  I finally figured out that if I turn on Media Share I can copy everything to my PC.  Over WiFi.  There's got to be a better way.

Comment: That's the [default](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/127508/131553) for marshmallow to connect in USB in *charging* mode. You have to change it you can try [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/132079/131553)

Comment: @beeshyams I don't think that's what's happening here, because there's no notification at all, not even a "USB for charging". Also the question you linked is about changing the default, not just about getting it to work at all.

Comment: Funny, just yesterday I had a similar experience trying to connect my camera to a relative's Windows 10 laptop, ended up having to grab a recent firmware update for the camera, the changelog for which basically just said "Windows 10 compatibility"... so it's not just you.

Comment: OK, I just noticed that the **phone** has a message that says "Connected for charging" if you pull down the menu from the top of the phone.  It also has an option to connect to transfer files.  So this isn't a Windows issue, it's an Android issue.  I've seen about 30 pages (including on Microsoft's forum on their website) where people are going ballistic thinking it's a Windows issue.  Hopefully in the future people will find this post and take a closer look at their phones.

Comment: 10,000 views, not a single upvote.  That's gotta be some sort of stack exchange record.  :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to drop this in as an answer, since it solved my problem.  Credit goes to **beeshyams** and **Dan Hulme** who set me on the path to see this.

The issue is an Android issue, not a Windows 10 issue.  Apparently Android's new OS defaults to *charging* due to a perceived security issue.  When you connect your phone to your PC, pull down the menu from the top of the phone (start at the top of your phone's screen and swipe downward).  You should see a message saying that you are connected for charging:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Press on that message and you will see a screen where you can change how you're connected.  On that screen, choose Transferring media files:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Now, if you go back to the first pulldown menu, you'll see you're connected as a media device:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Go back to your PC desktop and open File Explorer and VOILA!  You can now copy your data to your PC.